# What is ahk_class? How can I use it for window matching?

Tags: autohotkey

The [AutoHotkey Beginner Tutorial](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) includes a [sample script](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm#s22) to demonstrate window specific hotkeys and hotstrings.

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
::msg::You typed msg in Notepad
#IfWinActive

#IfWinActive untitled - Paint
::msg::You typed msg in MSPaint!
#IfWinActive
```

The second example is fairly self-explanatory: Check for a window named "untitled - Paint". It's the first example's use of `ahk_class` that has me confused.

I haven't been able to find any explanation of the variable in  the [AHK documentation](https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=010629462602499112316:ywoq_rufgic&q=ahk_class#gsc.tab=0&gsc.q=ahk_class&gsc.ref=more%3Adocumentation&gsc.sort=). [According to an AHK forum post](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/46919-help-about-ahk-class/?p=292345), `ahk_class` is the name of a window as given by Windows Spy, the post didn't go into any more detail.

Would there be any difference between using `ahk_class Notepad` and `Untitled - Notepad`? Would the second example work if replaced with `#IfWinActive ahk_class Paint`?

**What is `ahk_class` and how can I use it for window matching?**

Comment: Additional note: I'm using the portable version of AutoHotkey, [which does not include WindowSpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552452/could-not-launch-file-au3-spy-exe).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#ahk_class

> A window class is a set of attributes that the system uses as a template to create a window. In other words, the class name of the window identifies what type of window it is.

In other words you can use it to identify windows of the same type, if you open notepad the title will be `Untitled - Notepad` if you save it to `temp.txt` the title will become `temp - Notepad`. `ahk_class` on the other hand will always remain `Notepad`.

The second example will work if you replace it with `#IfWinActive ahk_class MSPaintApp` because that's the class of mspaint.

Usually you find `ahk_class` using `Window Spy` and then use it in your scripts. If you don't have `Window Spy` you can use the following hotkey:

```
#1::WinGetClass, Clipboard, A ; Will copy the ahk_class of the Active Window to clipboard
```

After you found it you can use it in any place you can use window title for example instead of writing `WinActivate, Untitled - Notepad` you can write `WinActivate, ahk_class Notepad`.

Comment: So `ahk_class` is looking for the program name, rather than the window name.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It's not exactly the program name, one program can have different types of windows, and different programs can sometimes have the same ahk_class. For now just think about it as the program name, and use it to identify a program.

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/46919-help-about-ahk-class/) article. Ahk_class is the class that is given to you when you use the WindowSpy tool. This tool should be in the same folder as your AutoHotkey executable.

Comment: I specifically referenced that forum post in my answer to say it did not help. My version of AutoHotkey [does not have the WindowsSpy tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45552452/could-not-launch-file-au3-spy-exe).