# assign different border to different windows?

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

**Hotkeys and hotstrings problem :**

Now It seems to be working well and the flashing problem no longer occurs But I have this script for test only :

- when pressing m, a MsgBox should apppear but It does not.
- when commenting the script that draws borders or the SetTimer and then when pressing m the MsgBox appears.
  Is the problem from the border's script or what?

```
#SingleInstance Force
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
SendMode("Input")
Persistent
SetWorkingDir(A_ScriptDir) ; Ensures a consistent starting directory
SetTitleMatchMode(2)
ProcessSetPriority("High")
SetTimer test, 1000
test() {
    WinWaitActive("ahk_class Notepad")
    WinWaitNotActive("ahk_class Notepad")
    SoundBeep(1000)
}
; =================================================================
; used in SetWinEventHook (for eventMin and eventMax)
; check here for additional events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants
global EVENT_SYSTEM_ALERT := 0x2 ; 2 - alert has been generated
global EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND := 0x3 ; 3 - foreground window changed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART := 0x4 ; 4 - menu-bar menu opened
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND := 0x5 ; 5 - menu-bar menu closed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART := 0x6 ; 6 - pop-up menu opened
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPEND := 0x7 ; 7 - pop-up menu closed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART := 0x8 ; 8 - mouse click start
global EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND := 0x9 ; 9 - mouse click end
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART := 0xA ; 10 - window move/resize start
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND := 0xB ; 11 - window move/resize end
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGSTART := 0x12 ; 18 - scrolling started on a scrol bar
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGEND := 0x13 ; 19 - scrolling ended on a scrol bar
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART := 0x14 ; 20 - alt+tab pressed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND := 0x15 ; 21 - alt+tab released
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART := 0x16 ; 22 - window minimized
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND := 0x17 ; 23 - window restored from minimize
global WINDOW_DRAG_STARTED := 0x19 ; 25 - window drag start (documentation not found for this)
global EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH := 0x20 ; 32 - active desktop has switched
global EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE := 0x8000 ; 32768 - an object has been created
global EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY := 0x8001 ; 32769 - an object has been destroyed
global EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW := 0x8002 ; 32770 - a hidden object is shown
global EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE := 0x800B ; 32779 - an object has changed location, shape, or size
global EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE := 0x800C ; 32780 - an object's Name property has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE := 0x800E ; 32782 - an object's Value property has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_PARENTCHANGE := 0x800F ; 32783 - an object has a new parent object
global EVENT_OBJECT_CLOAKED := 0x8017 ; 32791 - a window is cloaked. A cloaked window still exists, but is invisible to the user.
global EVENT_OBJECT_UNCLOAKED := 0x8018 ; 32792 - a window is uncloaked. A cloaked window still exists, but is invisible to the user.
; used in SetWinEventHook (for dwFlags)
global WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT := 0x0000 ; Events are ASYNC
global WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD := 0x0001 ; Don't call back for events generated by this thread
global WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS := 0x0002 ; Don't call back for events generated by threads of this process
; used with the callback function of SetWinEventHook (for idObject and idChild)
global OBJID_WINDOW := 0x00000000 ; 0
global OBJID_SYSMENU := 0xFFFFFFFF ; -1
global OBJID_TITLEBAR := 0xFFFFFFFE ; -2
global OBJID_MENU := 0xFFFFFFFD ; -3
global OBJID_CLIENT := 0xFFFFFFFC ; -4
global OBJID_VSCROLL := 0xFFFFFFFB ; -5
global OBJID_HSCROLL := 0xFFFFFFFA ; -6
global OBJID_SIZEGRIP := 0xFFFFFFF9 ; -7
global OBJID_CARET := 0xFFFFFFF8 ; -8
global OBJID_CURSOR := 0xFFFFFFF7 ; -9
global OBJID_ALERT := 0xFFFFFFF6 ; -10
global OBJID_SOUND := 0xFFFFFFF5 ; -11
global OBJID_QUERYCLASSNAMEIDX := 0xFFFFFFF4 ; -12
global OBJID_NATIVEOM := 0xFFFFFFF3 ; -13
global CHILDID_SELF := 0
; saved for releasing resources appropriately
global hookProcAdr := ""
global hWinEventHooks := []
; list of windows for which to create a border
; Title is what will be matched with WinActive(Title)
; if the final list entry's Title is "A", it will make the current active window be the "fallback" if none of the others match
global rectList := [{
    Title: "ahk_class PotPlayer64",
    Rect: DrawRect(2, 'green', 0)
}, {
    Title: "ahk_exe vivaldi.exe",
    Rect: DrawRect(2, 'yellow', 2)
}, {
    Title: "ahk_exe Reverso.exe",
    Rect: DrawRect(2, 'red', 0)
}, {
    ;     Title: "Program Manager",
    ;     Rect: DrawRect(2, '33cc33', 2)
    ; }, {
    Title: "- Notepad",
    Rect: DrawRect(4, 'green', 1)
}, {
    Title: "Microsoft Store",
    Rect: DrawRect(2, 'red', 3)
}, {
    Title: "A",
    Rect: DrawRect()
}
]
class DrawRect extends Gui {
    __New(border_thickness := "3", border_color := "red", offset := 0) {
        super.__New("+AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow", "GUI4Boarder")
        super.BackColor := border_color
        super.Opt("+E0x08080028") ; WS_EX_NOACTIVATE|WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT|WS_EX_TOPMOST
        DllCall("SetLayeredWindowAttributes", "Ptr", super.Hwnd, "Ptr", 0, "UChar", 255, "UInt", 2, "Int") ; allows this "Layered Window" to be visible and makes it fully opaque (i.e. 255)
        this.offset := offset
        this.parentHwnd := 0
        this.x := 0
        this.y := 0
        this.w := 0
        this.h := 0
        this.outerX := offset
        this.outerY := offset
        this.innerX := border_thickness + offset
        this.innerY := border_thickness + offset
        this.IsShowing := false
    }
    UpdatePosition(hwnd) {
        this.parentHwnd := hwnd
        super.Opt("+Owner" this.parentHwnd)
        WinGetPos(&x, &y, &w, &h, this.parentHwnd)
        if (x == this.x && y == this.y && w == this.w && h == this.h)
            return false ; position is the same as the last time this was checked
        this.x := x
        this.y := y
        this.w := w
        this.h := h
        return true
    }
    Show() {
        outerX2 := this.w - this.outerX
        outerY2 := this.h - this.outerY
        innerX2 := this.w - this.innerX
        innerY2 := this.h - this.innerY
        WinSetRegion(this.outerX "-" this.outerY " " outerX2 "-" this.outerY " " outerX2 "-" outerY2 " " this.outerX "-" outerY2 " " this.outerX "-" this.outerY " " this.innerX "-" this.innerY " " innerX2 "-" this.innerY " " innerX2 "-" innerY2 " " this.innerX "-" innerY2 " " this.innerX "-" this.innerY, super.Hwnd)
        ; super.Show("w" . this.w . " h" . this.h . " x" . this.x . " y" . this.y . " NoActivate")
        ; Similar to super.OptShow("+E0x800A8"whxy) but also places it at the top of the z-order
        DllCall("SetWindowPos", "Ptr", super.Hwnd, "Ptr", 0, "Int", this.x, "Int", this.y, "Int", this.w, "Int", this.h, "UInt", 0x4250, "Int") ; SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOOWNERZORDER|SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS (0x10|0x40|0x200|0x4000)
        this.IsShowing := true
    }
    Hide() {
        super.Hide()
        this.IsShowing := false
    }
}
ShowRect(hWinEventHook, Event, hWnd, idObject := 0, idChild := 0, dwEventThread := 0, dwmsEventTime := 0) {
    Critical -1 ; turns on Critical (making the thread uninterruptible) but disables message checks (via -1)
    ; ignore events for objects that are not windows and events for child objects
    if (idObject !== OBJID_WINDOW || idChild !== CHILDID_SELF)
        return
    for _, value in rectList {
        ; the latter two WinActive checks will exclude the Windows Desktop itself from matching but you can remove them if you aren't using a WinActive("A") gui
        if ((winHwnd := WinActive(value.Title)) && !WinActive("ahk_class WorkerW ahk_exe explorer.exe") && !WinActive("ahk_class Progman ahk_exe explorer.exe")) {
            ; current active window matches one in the list
            try {
                if (WinGetMinMax("ahk_id " winHwnd) == 0) {
                    ; window is not maximized or minimized
                    if (value.Rect.UpdatePosition(winHwnd) || !value.Rect.IsShowing) {
                        ; window is in a new position or the gui was previously hidden
                        value.Rect.Show()
                    }
                    continue
                }
            }
            ; active window has been maximized, minimized, or no longer exists, so hide the rect
            value.Rect.Hide()
            continue
        }
        ; hide any existing rects for non-matching windows
        if (value.Rect.IsShowing) {
            value.Rect.Hide()
            continue
        }
    }
}
SetWinEventHook(eventMin, eventMax, hmodWinEventProc, lpfnWinEventProc, idProcess, idThread, dwFlags) {
    return DllCall("SetWinEventHook"
        , "UInt", eventMin ; start of event range
        , "UInt", eventMax ; end of event range
        , "UInt", hmodWinEventProc ; handle to DLL that contains the hook function or null
        , "UInt", lpfnWinEventProc ; the callback
        , "UInt", idProcess ; process IDs of interest (0 = all)
        , "UInt", idThread ; thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
        , "UInt", dwFlags ; flags
        , "Ptr") ; returns HWINEVENTHOOK
}
ReleaseResources(ExitReason, ExitCode) {
    global hookProcAdr, hWinEventHook
    loop hWinEventHooks.Length {
        DllCall("UnhookWinEvent", "Ptr", hWinEventHooks.Pop()) ; free up memory from SetWinEventHook
    }
    if (hookProcAdr) {
        CallbackFree(hookProcAdr) ; free up allocated memory from CallbackCreate
        hookProcAdr := ""
    }
}
OnExit(ReleaseResources)
hookProcAdr := CallbackCreate(ShowRect, , 7) ; avoiding fast mode because it may be called from a different thread
; hook on active window change
hWinEventHooks.Push(SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 0, hookProcAdr, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS))
; hook on window move/resize
hWinEventHooks.Push(SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, 0, hookProcAdr, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS))
ShowRect(0, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, WinActive("A")) ; Make a pseudo call when the script is called in order to affect the current active window as well
; =================================================================
m:: MsgBox("m")
```

Comment: Not hard. Just use `WinGetActiveTitle` at https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/WinGetActiveTitle.htm and set those characteristics to variables.

Comment: I'm newbie, can you give me an example please!

Comment: The question "And How can I identify a window by its window class ahk_class or process name ahk_exe or ahk_group instead of the classic window title." should probably be a separate question, though I'm almost certain [another question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45645435) would be sufficient to answer that.

Comment: But the short answer I'd give is use `Window Spy.exe` in the installation directory of AutoHotkey. It can also be launched by right-clicking the AutoHotkey icon in the taskbar and choosing `Window Spy`

Comment: Please refrain from making edits to a question that change the nature of the question or make it difficult for new viewers to ascertain how the answers relate to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Version 1

Here is one way to do what @PGilm was suggesting. It's not the most eloquent solution, but it should work for your needs.

You could put something like this inside the `Call()` method of `DrawRect`, after these first four lines

```
        if (win := this.func()) && WinGetMinMax(win) == 0 {
            WinGetPos(&x, &y, &w, &h, win)
            offset := this.offset
            border_thickness := this.border_thickness
```

add

```
            title := WinGetTitle("ahk_id " win)
            if (title ~= "- Notepad$") {
                border_thickness := 4
                offset := 1
                super.BackColor := "green"
            } else if (title == "Microsoft Store") {
                border_thickness := 2
                offset := 3
                super.BackColor := "red"
            } else {
                super.BackColor := this.border_color
            }
```

additionally, you'll need to change the line in the `__New()` method from

```
        super.BackColor := border_color
```

to

```
        this.border_color := border_color
```

in order to store the default `border_color`.

What's happening is that `SetTimer` is being passed a function object and its `Call()` method will be called every 100 milliseconds.

If I were writing it from scratch, to make it more versatile, I would probably have separate objects set up and then call the right one depending on the current active window.

---

## Version 2

An alternative way of doing this is to watch for the `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` and `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE` messages being sent by the system via `SetWinEventHook` and then show/hide the rect's appropriately.

By doing is this way, you won't have a bunch of `SetTimer`s running in the background eating up cpu or memory. However, the rects also won't *go away* after a predetermined period of time this way. `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE` *should* account for this in most situations, but in the event that you want to watch for additional system events, I'll include a list of a number of them at the top and also a link to view more of them.

```
Persistent ; Keep the script running even when there are no hotkeys or timers

; used in SetWinEventHook (for eventMin and eventMax)
; check here for additional events: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/event-constants
global EVENT_SYSTEM_ALERT := 0x2 ; 2 - alert has been generated
global EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND := 0x3 ; 3 - foreground window changed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART := 0x4 ; 4 - menu-bar menu opened
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND := 0x5 ; 5 - menu-bar menu closed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART := 0x6 ; 6 - pop-up menu opened
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPEND := 0x7 ; 7 - pop-up menu closed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART := 0x8 ; 8 - mouse click start
global EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND := 0x9 ; 9 - mouse click end
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART := 0xA ; 10 - window move/resize start
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND := 0xB ; 11 - window move/resize end
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGSTART := 0x12 ; 18 - scrolling started on a scrol bar
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGEND := 0x13 ; 19 - scrolling ended on a scrol bar
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART := 0x14 ; 20 - alt+tab pressed
global EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND := 0x15 ; 21 - alt+tab released
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART := 0x16 ; 22 - window minimized
global EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND := 0x17 ; 23 - window restored from minimize
global WINDOW_DRAG_STARTED := 0x19 ; 25 - window drag start (documentation not found for this)
global EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH := 0x20 ; 32 - active desktop has switched
global EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE := 0x8000 ; 32768 - an object has been created
global EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY := 0x8001 ; 32769 - an object has been destroyed
global EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW := 0x8002 ; 32770 - a hidden object is shown
global EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE := 0x800B ; 32779 - an object has changed location, shape, or size
global EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE := 0x800C ; 32780 - an object's Name property has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE := 0x800E ; 32782 - an object's Value property has changed
global EVENT_OBJECT_PARENTCHANGE := 0x800F ; 32783 - an object has a new parent object
global EVENT_OBJECT_CLOAKED := 0x8017 ; 32791 - a window is cloaked. A cloaked window still exists, but is invisible to the user.
global EVENT_OBJECT_UNCLOAKED := 0x8018 ; 32792 - a window is uncloaked. A cloaked window still exists, but is invisible to the user.

; used in SetWinEventHook (for dwFlags)
global WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT := 0x0000 ; Events are ASYNC
global WINEVENT_SKIPOWNTHREAD := 0x0001 ; Don't call back for events generated by this thread
global WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS := 0x0002 ; Don't call back for events generated by threads of this process

; used with the callback function of SetWinEventHook (for idObject and idChild)
global OBJID_WINDOW := 0x00000000 ; 0
global OBJID_SYSMENU := 0xFFFFFFFF ; -1
global OBJID_TITLEBAR := 0xFFFFFFFE ; -2
global OBJID_MENU := 0xFFFFFFFD ; -3
global OBJID_CLIENT := 0xFFFFFFFC ; -4
global OBJID_VSCROLL := 0xFFFFFFFB ; -5
global OBJID_HSCROLL := 0xFFFFFFFA ; -6
global OBJID_SIZEGRIP := 0xFFFFFFF9 ; -7
global OBJID_CARET := 0xFFFFFFF8 ; -8
global OBJID_CURSOR := 0xFFFFFFF7 ; -9
global OBJID_ALERT := 0xFFFFFFF6 ; -10
global OBJID_SOUND := 0xFFFFFFF5 ; -11
global OBJID_QUERYCLASSNAMEIDX := 0xFFFFFFF4 ; -12
global OBJID_NATIVEOM := 0xFFFFFFF3 ; -13
global CHILDID_SELF := 0

; saved for releasing resources appropriately
global hookProcAdr := ""
global hWinEventHooks := []

; list of windows for which to create a border
; Title is what will be matched with WinActive(Title)
; if the final list entry's Title is "A", it will make the current active window be the "fallback" if none of the others match
global rectList := [
    {Title: "ahk_class PotPlayer64", Rect: DrawRect(2, 'green', 0)},
    {Title: "ahk_exe vivaldi.exe", Rect: DrawRect(2, 'yellow', 2)},
    {Title: "ahk_exe Reverso.exe", Rect: DrawRect(2, 'red', 0)},
    {Title: "ahk_group desktop", Rect: DrawRect(2, '33cc33', 2)},
    {Title: "- Notepad", Rect: DrawRect(4, 'green', 1)},
    {Title: "Microsoft Store", Rect: DrawRect(2, 'red', 3)},
    {Title: "A", Rect: DrawRect()}
]

class DrawRect extends Gui {
    __New(border_thickness := "3", border_color := "red", offset := 0) {
        super.__New("+AlwaysOnTop -Caption +ToolWindow", "GUI4Boarder")
        super.BackColor := border_color
        super.Opt("+E0x08080028") ; WS_EX_NOACTIVATE|WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_EX_TRANSPARENT|WS_EX_TOPMOST
        DllCall("SetLayeredWindowAttributes", "Ptr",super.Hwnd, "Ptr",0, "UChar",255, "UInt",2, "Int") ; allows this "Layered Window" to be visible and makes it fully opaque (i.e. 255)
        this.offset := offset
        this.parentHwnd := 0
        this.x := 0
        this.y := 0
        this.w := 0
        this.h := 0
        this.outerX := offset
        this.outerY := offset
        this.innerX := border_thickness + offset
        this.innerY := border_thickness + offset
        this.IsShowing := false
    }
    UpdatePosition(hwnd) {
        this.parentHwnd := hwnd
        super.Opt("+Owner" this.parentHwnd)
        WinGetPos(&x, &y, &w, &h, this.parentHwnd)
        if (x == this.x && y == this.y && w == this.w && h == this.h)
            return false ; position is the same as the last time this was checked
        this.x := x
        this.y := y
        this.w := w
        this.h := h
        return true
    }
    Show() {
        outerX2 := this.w - this.outerX
        outerY2 := this.h - this.outerY
        innerX2 := this.w - this.innerX
        innerY2 := this.h - this.innerY
        WinSetRegion(this.outerX "-" this.outerY " " outerX2 "-" this.outerY " " outerX2 "-" outerY2 " " this.outerX "-" outerY2 " " this.outerX "-" this.outerY " " this.innerX "-" this.innerY " " innerX2 "-" this.innerY " " innerX2 "-" innerY2 " " this.innerX "-" innerY2 " " this.innerX "-" this.innerY, super.Hwnd)
        ; super.Show("w" . this.w . " h" . this.h . " x" . this.x . " y" . this.y . " NoActivate")
        ; Similar to super.Show(whxy) but also places it at the top of the z-order
        DllCall("SetWindowPos", "Ptr",super.Hwnd, "Ptr",0, "Int",this.x, "Int",this.y, "Int",this.w, "Int",this.h, "UInt",0x4250, "Int") ; SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_SHOWWINDOW|SWP_NOOWNERZORDER|SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS (0x10|0x40|0x200|0x4000)
        this.IsShowing := true
    }
    Hide() {
        super.Hide()
        this.IsShowing := false
    }
}

ShowRect(hWinEventHook, Event, hWnd, idObject:=0, idChild:=0, dwEventThread:=0, dwmsEventTime:=0) {
    Critical -1 ; turns on Critical (making the thread uninterruptible) but disables message checks (via -1)
    ; ignore events for objects that are not windows and events for child objects
    if (idObject !== OBJID_WINDOW || idChild !== CHILDID_SELF)
        return
    for _,value in rectList {
        ; the latter two WinActive checks will exclude the Windows Desktop itself from matching but you can remove them if you aren't using a WinActive("A") gui
        if ((winHwnd := WinActive(value.Title)) && !WinActive("ahk_class WorkerW ahk_exe explorer.exe") && !WinActive("ahk_class Progman ahk_exe explorer.exe")) {
            ; current active window matches one in the list
            try {
                if (WinGetMinMax("ahk_id " winHwnd) == 0) {
                    ; window is not maximized or minimized
                    if (value.Rect.UpdatePosition(winHwnd) || !value.Rect.IsShowing) {
                        ; window is in a new position or the gui was previously hidden
                        value.Rect.Show()
                    }
                    continue
                }
            }
            ; active window has been maximized, minimized, or no longer exists, so hide the rect
            value.Rect.Hide()
            continue
        }
        ; hide any existing rects for non-matching windows
        if (value.Rect.IsShowing) {
            value.Rect.Hide()
            continue
        }
    }
}

SetWinEventHook(eventMin, eventMax, hmodWinEventProc, lpfnWinEventProc, idProcess, idThread, dwFlags) {
    return DllCall("SetWinEventHook"
        ,"UInt",eventMin ; start of event range
        ,"UInt",eventMax ; end of event range
        ,"UInt",hmodWinEventProc ; handle to DLL that contains the hook function or null
        ,"UInt",lpfnWinEventProc ; the callback
        ,"UInt",idProcess ; process IDs of interest (0 = all)
        ,"UInt",idThread ; thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
        ,"UInt",dwFlags ; flags
        ,"Ptr") ; returns HWINEVENTHOOK
}

ReleaseResources(ExitReason, ExitCode) {
    global hookProcAdr, hWinEventHook
    loop hWinEventHooks.Length {
        DllCall("UnhookWinEvent", "Ptr",hWinEventHooks.Pop()) ; free up memory from SetWinEventHook
    }
    if (hookProcAdr) {
        CallbackFree(hookProcAdr) ; free up allocated memory from CallbackCreate
        hookProcAdr := ""
    }
}

OnExit(ReleaseResources)

hookProcAdr := CallbackCreate(ShowRect, , 7) ; avoiding fast mode because it may be called from a different thread

; hook on active window change
hWinEventHooks.Push(SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 0, hookProcAdr, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT|WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS))
; hook on window move/resize
hWinEventHooks.Push(SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, 0, hookProcAdr, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT|WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS))

ShowRect(0, EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, WinActive("A")) ; Make a pseudo call when the script is called in order to affect the current active window as well
```

I also moved some of the expressions to the `__New()` method for a minimal optimization.

##### Edit:

Added an `UpdatePosition(hwnd)` method that returns false if the position is unchanged and modified the `Show()` method and callsites of it accordingly.

---

## Version 2.5

Here is a version that I was playing around with until I settled on the `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE` event. To be clear, this is an "incomplete" solution compared to Version 2, but it may assist you in debugging things yourself.

Just replace the `ShowRect` method in Version 2 with the one below and modify the additional line below that. There are some superfluous switch cases accounted for, since the only events that will show up are the ones that you include in the `SetWinHookEvent`. However, the main problem with this version is that it won't account for situations like where you maximize the window.

```
ShowRect(hWinEventHook, Event, hWnd, idObject:=0, idChild:=0, dwEventThread:=0, dwmsEventTime:=0) {
    ; ignore events for objects that are not windows and events for child objects
    if (idObject !== OBJID_WINDOW || idChild !== CHILDID_SELF)
        return
    switch (Event) {
        case EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGSTART
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_SCROLLINGEND
            , EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE
            , EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY
            , EVENT_OBJECT_SHOW
            , EVENT_OBJECT_NAMECHANGE
            , EVENT_OBJECT_VALUECHANGE
            , EVENT_OBJECT_PARENTCHANGE:
            ; do nothing
            return
        case EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZESTART
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_MOVESIZEEND
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPSTART
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUPOPUPEND
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTURESTART
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_CAPTUREEND
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHEND
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZEEND
            , WINDOW_DRAG_STARTED
            , EVENT_OBJECT_UNCLOAKED:
            for _,value in rectList {
                ; the latter two WinActive checks will exclude the Windows Desktop itself from matching but you can remove them if you aren't using a WinActive("A") gui
                if ((winHwnd := WinActive(value.Title)) && !WinActive("ahk_class WorkerW ahk_exe explorer.exe") && !WinActive("ahk_class Progman ahk_exe explorer.exe")) {
                    ; current active window matches one in the list
                    try {
                        if (WinGetMinMax("ahk_id " winHwnd) == 0) {
                            ; window is not maximized or minimized
                            if (value.Rect.UpdatePosition(winHwnd) || !value.Rect.IsShowing) {
                                ; window is in a new position or the gui was previously hidden
                                value.Rect.Show()
                            }
                            continue
                        }
                    }
                    ; active window has been maximized, minimized, or no longer exists, so hide the rect
                    value.Rect.Hide()
                    continue
                }
                ; hide any existing rects for non-matching windows
                if (value.Rect.IsShowing) {
                    value.Rect.Hide()
                    continue
                }
            }
        case EVENT_SYSTEM_ALERT
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_MINIMIZESTART
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_SWITCHSTART
            , EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH
            , EVENT_OBJECT_CLOAKED:
            ; hide any rects
            for _,value in rectList {
                if (value.Rect.IsShowing) {
                    value.Rect.Hide()
                    break
                }
            }
        default:
            ; hide any rects
            for _,value in rectList {
                if (value.Rect.IsShowing) {
                    value.Rect.Hide()
                    break
                }
            }
            return
    }
}
```

Then you can change the hooks to only include this one, which will hook on every event from `EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND` through `EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH` :

```
hWinEventHooks.Push(SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, EVENT_SYSTEM_DESKTOPSWITCH, 0, hookProcAdr, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT|WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS))
```

Or, alternatively, include only the exact ones you want to account for, similar to Version 2.

Comment: Thanks for help! It works with some windows But It doesn't work with some others windows e.g (PotPlayer, Vivaldi). I have edited the post ...

Comment: First of all, the reason you probably commented out the final `else {super.BackColor := this.border_color}` is probably because it wasn't working for other windows than the last one. If you're using the method I suggested, you need to make sure they're all chained in an `if (condition) { ... } else if (condition) { ... } else { ... }` pattern. That is, `else if` makes it so its condition will **only** be checked *if* the first `if` was unsuccessful.

Comment: And the final `else` will only be called if **none** of the prior `if`→`else if`s were successful.

Comment: @yfjuu0 I added an alternate version for if you'd like to hook into the system messages instead of having a bunch of `SetTimer`s.

Comment: V2 It works but the border sometimes blinks, if you will.
as shown here : https://imgur.com/a/G0QPI9O

Comment: Did you copy it as-is or did you modify it? That would be likely to occur if you forgot to include the line `if (idObject !== OBJID_WINDOW || idChild !== CHILDID_SELF) { return }`, since the `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE` message will be sent for cursor location changes as well. If that's not the issue, then perhaps PotPlayer sends window updates for some other reason (probably every second when the track is playing), in which case you can try removing the `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE` event, but unfortunately that's the only way I could find to handle hooking into when the window maximizes.

Comment: If `EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE` is problematic for you, you can try Version 2.5. It's not a "complete" solution, however, since if you maximize the window, the border will remain where it was before, unaccounted for. Otherwise, there's probably some hacky way you can accomplish it with Version 2, like adding some sort of internal timer and ignore events that happen too quickly.

Comment: Another possible solution, using Version 2, would be to store the values of x,y,w,h inside the class and only trigger the `Show(hwnd)` method when they differ from before.

Comment: I updated Version 2 with an implementation of what my last comment suggested. If it's still flashing then it is likely that something is actively forcibly taking foreground window focus.

Comment: Ah, I neglected to mention that the changes I made to Version 2 are also used in Version 2.5. That's where `UpdatePosition` was added, as well as a number of other changes to `DrawRect` and `ShowRect` to match. I would suggest replacing the entire class with the updated one. It's a slight optimization so that the border isn't redrawn when nothing has changed. However, after thinking about it some more, I have realized what the issue probably is. It's possible I wasn't seeing it because my CPU/GPU are too fast. I'll update Version 2 with the new changes in a few minutes.

Comment: Hy, Have you updated It yet?

Comment: @yfjuu Yes. Look at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77688651/revisions) if you want to view the changes easier.

Comment: Now It seems to be working well and the flashing problem no longer occurs But I have this script for test only (Post edited)

Comment: Try removing the `Critical -1` line in `ShowRect` if your script has things that require thread interruption. However, the root of your problem involves the `SetTimer`. The way it's written, it'll often still be running when it tries to launch another instance, and the `WinWaitActive` will halt the thread indefinitely since it cannot be interrupted. In addition to removing `Critical -1`, you might add `Critical "Off"` in `test`. You should also read more about [Critical](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Critical.htm) and [SetTimer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/SetTimer.htm).

Comment: when I replaced Critical -1 with Critical "Off", everything is going well.
Is that what you mean?

Comment: That's one way to do it (or you can just remove the line entirely). However, the real problem is your test function, but aside from what I've already stated, that's far outside of the scope of this question.

Comment: Ok! Now, everything is working well. Thank you a lot! I so appreciate your great help.