# Is there a way in AHK or if possible in Pulover Macro Recorder to detect how many times an image occurs within an area?

Tags: macros, autohotkey, pulovers-macro-creator

I need a macro script or bot that can detect how many times an image occurs within a certain area of a screen and save that as a variable to be inputted or typed in.

I'm really new to AHK and is currently just using Pulover to make macros. I want to know if that's possible and the way to do it as well. I don't know where to start searching for topics on this subject so I'm very sorry if it's an easy or a common sense question.

I tried searching but can't really find something specific for my problem

[image]

Comment: Are the coordinates of that image always the same? How many times in which time interval (= frequency)? Is that frequency always the same?

Comment: @Relax Yes, and around 30 secs time interval?

Comment: Without basic AHK knowledge I doubt that you can manage to accomplish such a task. And without knowing the program that creates that image it is very difficult for someone else to help you.

Comment: @Relax A website creates the images. I edited my question to add a pic that shows exactly how it is gonna be. I want to count the images shown which in this case is the cherry and input that amount in the input box below

Comment: You can use  [PixelSearch](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/PixelSearch.htm) to find the position of the first image in that window. If you know that position, its easy to calculate the images amount.

Comment: @Relax I'm so sorry, but I still don't have any idea on how I can achieve that x.x. But thank you very much for the help

Comment: What shows the [Window Spy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45680175/3419297) tool when that window is active? While running a script, right-click the AHK icon in the notification area and select Window Spy.